# How to match the following with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

Assume I have the following string:

```
string = "** Hunger is the physical sensation of desiring food.                                      

<br>         Your Hunger Level: Very Hungery<br> Food You Crave: Tomato<br/><br/>"
```

I want to be able to extract out "Your Hunger" and "Tomato". Assume that regardless of what special characters are inserted, I know for a fact that "Your Hunger Level:" and "Food You Crave" will always be constant.

```
"Your Hunger Level:" could be: "Very Hungry", "Hungry", "Not So Hungry"
"Food You Crave:" could be: "Tomato", "Rice and Beans", "Corn Soup"
```

How do I use a regular expression to match this? I tried the following, but am not getting any luck...

```
m = re.match('(.*)([ \t]+)?Your Hunger Level:([ \t]+)?(?P<hungerlevel>.*)(.*)Food You Crave:([ \t]+)?(?P<foodcraving>.*).*', string)
```

NOTE: The string appears to have a lot of escape characters indicated below:

```
string = "** Hunger is the physical sensation of desiring food. <br>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tYour Hunger Level:
Very Hungry \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<br>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tFood You Crave: Tomato \n\t\t\t\t\t\t</br>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for:

```
print [map(str.strip, line.split(':')) for line in re.split('<.*?>', string) if ':' in line]
# [['Your Hunger Level', 'Very Hungery'], ['Food You Crave', 'Tomato']]
```

Or, you could make it a `dict`:

```
lookup = dict(map(str.strip, line.split(':')) for line in re.split('<.*?>', text) if ':' in line)
print lookup['Your Hunger Level']
# 'Very Hungry'
```

Comment: I tried that and it printed out a ton of these "hidden?" characters unbenowest to me, updated original post with the output.

Comment: @SeiSeiei Those are just tabs and newlines - running the above on your updated string still works as it strips all leading and trailing whitespace from it...

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to access the exact text: "Very Hungery", how would I do that assuming I knew that I would be expecting the "Hunger Level" to be the key? is there something like, theresultmap.get('Your Hunger Level')

Comment: @SeiSeiei As the result is a list of two-element items, you can change it to pass it to a dict (as key, value), and then use that as a lookup - see updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I definitely agree with using any sort of parser, but the following seems to work. It simply starts after your target word and goes until it hits a `<` (I do not endorse it for the record, but hopefully it works :) ):

```
In [28]: import re

In [29]: s = """** Hunger is the physical sensation of desiring food.
<br>         Your Hunger Level: Very Hungery<br> Food You Crave: Tomato<br/><br/>"""

In [31]: m = re.search(r'Your Hunger Level:([^<]*)<br>.*Food You Crave:([^<]*)', s)

In [32]: m.group(1).strip()
Out[32]: 'Very Hungery'

In [33]: m.group(2).strip()
Out[33]: 'Tomato'
```

The `strip()` is to trim whitespace - not sure what the setup of your string is, but this is conservative so that it handles cases where there is no space between the colon and the text. Also, I would recommend not using Python keywords as variable names (`string`, in this case) - it will make things easier for you in the long run :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First, parse the HTML with a parser.  There are many at your disposal, e.g. beautiful soup, lxml.
2. Second, search the document for `<br>` tags.
3. Third, do a search over the text of the tags for the text that you want, and return that tag.

Comment: I'm normally the first to recommend a proper HTML parser, but in this case, it's pointless... (as there really isn't any structure)

Comment: Even with beautiful soup, searching the document for <br> tags is unreliable as there may be a lot of <br> tags, potentially even scattered throughout the "Hunger<br> is a <br> physical..." so I wouldnt know which <br> it is I would want unless there was some way to search for a <br> with given criteria outside the tag.

Comment: @JonClements I was thinking that the fragment he posted is actually the output of a parse; that hunch turns out to be correct.  
@SeiSeiei If you have the element that returned your string's information, you can run a search over *that element*.  `element.findAll` works the same as `html.findAll`.

Comment: Ahh, if that's the case, then indeed `element.findAll(text=True)` could be a winner...

Comment: @SeiSeiei I'll vote for that too - anything that avoids regex is good in my book.

Comment: I've updated my post with what I have discovered the string really looks like, apparently there is all this hidden junk in the string I am trying to parse that looks like the above. If it is possible to avoid it, I would.

Comment: You search for `text in element.text`, and then `split()` and `strip()` the element text after you've isolated it.